Vuforia Get Model Name
I'm trying to get the name of the model. When I used this code it only shows "DeviceObserver"
private ObserverBehaviour mObserverBehaviour;

 mObserverBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();
        if (mObserverBehaviour){
             Debug.Log("Fetched: " + mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetFound());
        }

What is the right way to fetch the name of the 3D Model?

ObserverBehavior should have a TargetName method... https://developer.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverBehaviour.html#a956296549a30b3093652ca8d10008a28

As mentioned in the comment, you would have to use the Observer's TargetName. So, you attach a script with something like this to your target in the inspector:
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class TargetLogger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ObserverBehaviour mObserverBehaviour;

    void Start()
    {
        ObserverBehaviour mObserverBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();

        if (mObserverBehaviour != null)
        mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnTargetStatusChanged;
    }
    
    void OnTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour behaviour, TargetStatus status)
    {
        Debug.Log("Fetched: " + behaviour.TargetName + "\n" + "Status: " + status.Status);
    }
}

Also, there is the Default Observer EventHandler component for reporting the TargetName, Status, and StatusInfo. I recommend just using that to log the targets.
